# VSTS Packer Prevent Cleanup

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, packer, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to use the "Build immutable image" release step in VSTS to create an Azure VM image. Problem is the VM deployment to create the image is failing, but I can't see the errors in Azure because Packer/VSTS is cleaning up and deleting the resource group immediately after the failure.
Is there are way to have Packer in VSTS not cleanup after its self so I can debug this?

Comment: Do you check Skip temporary file cleanup during deprovision option in advanced section? This is the source code of that task: [PackerBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PackerBuild)

Comment: Based on [How to use Packer to create Windows virtual machine images in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer), to capture that source VM for use as an image, you must define a resource group and storage account. The output from the Packer build process is stored in this resource group and storage account. So, could you check the output in resource group and storage account (not the temp resource group).

Comment: @starain-MSFT unfortunately not. The resource group in the VSTS step is just the one that contains the storage account to write the image to, Packer creates (and deletes) it's own resource group during deployment, I can see that much in the log.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes, I checked that box, that does not seem to impact packer

Comment: Do you mean there isn't the log in that resource group and storage account?

Comment: The resource group I supply has no logs for this deployment, as it fails well before it would try to save an image to the storage account. The resource group where the failure occurs is the one generated by packer and is deleted

Comment: Try to set System.Debug variable to true and check whether there is detail error.

Answer (score 1):

Run packer with the argument `-on-error=ask`

Comment: This is a non interactive packer command through a VSTS release step, I'm not running packer directly.

Comment: Ok then just switch `ask` to `abort` and you have to clean up your self.